# Test relationship of firm investment to GDP individually or in a panel regression

Tags: regression

I need to test how responsive are firms' investment to the level of the country's GDP.   I have 90 firms, all in the same country;  10 annual observations for the GDP; and 10 annual observations for each firm's investment level. Do I have to test the relation for each firm separately; if yes is it possible to run a regression with only 10 observations?  Alternatively can I use panel data regression, noting that the level of GDP is the same for all firms in a given year; it changes only over time not across firms.

Comment: You asked this question twice! And in the another one you have been asked for more information. Is nearly impossible to respond you if you don't express this problem clearly.

Comment: what type of information you need

Comment: i gave you variables and every detail

Comment: The previous question seems to have been removed, a clear community judgement that it was too difficult to answer. Repeating the question is most unlikely to trigger a change of view on this.

Comment: You need to be more precise. In order to answer you, I need to know how data has been collected, which regression model seems more adequate for you if you want to do a regression (you are the researcher, right?), if you suppose an AR(p) process, etc. In StackExchange you can find answers for your questions, but don't hope that others do your work.

Comment: I've edited the question to try to make a little clearer, check that the meaning is still accurate; and consider if there are any more details you can add to answer the queries from the other commenters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have also other data for firm (such as profit, and so on),you can use a panel data analysis tools. You can run one-way or two-way fixed effect (or random effect). There are test like Hausman test to decide whether to choose one over another. Please check [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CFYQFjAE&url=http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101R.pdf&ei=nWLsUZXbHuiEygHrxoGQDg&usg=AFQjCNElxZCZTVp5UGIO1BWiFNw8FuHD6g&bvm=bv.49478099,d.aWc) for doing analysis in R and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CE0QFjAF&url=http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101.pdf&ei=p2LsUbzfMoiqyAHt3oCYBg&usg=AFQjCNEZZLkH71zoBE5_w-0xApKAgBQNwg&bvm=bv.49478099,d.aWc) for doing analysis in Stata.

Comment: did u mean to use other data for firm as another independent variables or what?

Comment: yes, one that determines the firm's investment. You need to go back to the literature and find these.